# Having trouble with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Here is my code:

```
preg_match_all('/<a href="(.+?)index.php(.+?)&abc=(.+?)"/', $dataToParse, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $val)
{
    $absUrl = $val[1] . 'index.php' . $val[2] . '&abc=' . $val[3];

    echo $absUrl;
}
```

However, `$val[1]` is the entire matched string, including the `<a href`. I believe I have the syntax wrong but I have been trying to fix it with no luck. Not sure how to do this properly.

Comment: Doing it properly would involve a DOM parser instead of using regex to parse HTML.

Comment: It's 2013. Use an XML parser.

Comment: @JackManey: Inherited a project with other people who are doing it this way.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Comment: e's not parsing HTML, e's parsing a URL.

Comment: @JohnSmith - Then show them why parsing HTML with regexes is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing the constant `PREG_SET_ORDER` after the `$matches` one, like so:

```
preg_match_all("/.../",$dataToParse,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

For more information as to why, see the [documentation](http://php.net/preg-match-all)

Answer (score 0):

$matches[0] is the whole string, $matches[1] is the first match group, $matches[2] the second match group and so on.

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $matches[1]); $i++)
{
    $absUrl = $matches[1][$i] . 'index.php' . $matches[2][$i] . '&abc=' . $matches[3][$i];
    echo $absUrl;
}
```

Comment: there be ghosts in mah answers.